# Xcopy Script for Changing Directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy, xcopy

I'm currently trying to come up with a script to copy several files from one location to the operating location of a program and then launching the application. Currently I have this:

```
xcopy /s /v /z "I:\test\20150520\Files\stmt" "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test2"
PAUSE
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE
```

This script seems to work without a problem but the issue I'm running into is that my from directory changes each day where I have *20150520*. The directory's below that are always the same its just the one changes daily and I would need the script to do that as well.

Is there anyway that this can be done?

Comment: Generally, you can use _either_ current system date _or_ last date under `I:\test\` _or_ pass date to your script as a parameter _or_ ask an user for input. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Passing the date as parameter would be more of what I would want to use. I'm trying to get the script set up in a way that requires the least amount of user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next script expects a valid parameter (see `%~1` in the code and example provided below); if a parameter not found or does not match a valid folder then gets today's date (see the `:getToday` subroutine).

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "dayFolder=%~1"
if "%dayFolder%"==""                           call :getToday
if not exist "I:\test\%dayFolder%\Files\stmt\" call :getToday

if exist "I:\test\%dayFolder%\Files\stmt\" (
    xcopy /s /v /z "I:\test\%dayFolder%\Files\stmt" "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test2"
) else (
    echo invalid "%~1" parameter or "%dayFolder%" folder does not exist
)
PAUSE
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE

goto :eof
:getToday
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (
    'wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value'
) do @for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%G") do (
    set "dayFolder=%%~x"
)
set "dayFolder=%dayFolder:~0,8%"
goto :eof
```

Here the `for` loops in the `:getToday` subroutine are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `LocalDateTime` value;
- `%%x` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`).

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30356205.bat
invalid "" parameter or "20150521" folder does not exist
Press any key to continue . . .

==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30356205.bat 2015 05 19
invalid "2015" parameter or "20150521" folder does not exist
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: @Eric If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
::get today's date
set a=%date%
::format the date to MMYYDD
set b=%a:/=%
set full=%b%
::erase mon, tue, wed, thu etc
set full=%full:mon=%
set full=%full:tue=%
set full=%full:wed=%
set full=%full:thu=%
set full=%full:fri=%
set full=%full:sat=%
set full=%full:sun=%
pause
xcopy /s /v /z "I:\test\%full%\Files\stmt" "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test2"
PAUSE
C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE
```

Comment: This script ran today returns 05212015Thu instead of just 20150521.

Comment: i have a formatted code for you. give me the details of your time and date format either yyyymmdd or ddmmyyyy.